# Try to serialize Object although Validation fails

Tags: swift, alamofire

I use ResponseObjectSerializable like described here:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization

And i want to validate if the status code is in a range
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#validation

My call looks like this:

```
Alamofire.request(Router.Something())
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseObject { (request, response, object:Object?, error) in
            println(object)
            println(request)
            println(response)
}
```

My Problem is if the validation fails responseObject anyhow get called and try to serialize the empty response.
How I can handle that without validate the response a second time in my ResponseObjectSerializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really good question.

The long story short is that you can't. Your `responseObject` serializer is not notified about a validation error. It only receives the `request`, `response` and `data` objects and needs to attempt to construct the `object` from the data.

The [ResponseObjectSerializable](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization) link you posted does exactly that. If the serialization succeeds, it will return a valid object. If it fails, it will return a nil object and a serialization error.

Where it gets interesting is if you return a serialization error, but the validation also failed. In that case, your `completionHandler` will actually be called with a nil object, and the validation error, not the serialization error. Alamofire prioritizes the validation error over the serialization error if the validation is run before the `responseObject`.

> As a sidenote, your `responseObject` serializer should handle the data coming back from the server safely, regardless of the status code that was returned. If parsing the data fails, your serializer should return a serialization error. If it succeeds, then return the object.